# Strange argument parsing in write.csv

Tags: r

Consider the following two commands:

```
> write.csv(irfilt,'foo.bar',row.names=FALSE)
#works fine but: 
> write.csv(irfilt,'foo.bar',row.n=FALSE)
Error in write.table(irfilt, "foo.bar", row.n = FALSE, col.names = NA,  : 
  'col.names = NA' makes no sense when 'row.names = FALSE'
```

I would have expected `row.n` to auto-expand to `row.names` but apparently that's not happening.  There isn't any other allowed argument to `write.table` which could be confused with `row.names`.  Does anyone know what is causing this misinterpretation?  I thought it might be related to the fact that `write.csv` has no named arguments, but it seems odd that I wouldn't just get an error message about an unknown argument, rather than a misinterpreted arg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get any [partial argument matching](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching) inside of `write.csv` because `write.csv`'s only argument is `...`.  So `write.csv`'s attempt to manipulate your call fails here:

```
rn <- eval.parent(Call$row.names)
Call$col.names <- if (is.logical(rn) && !rn) TRUE else NA
```

And `row.n` is matched to `row.names` in the call to `write.table`, but the `write.table` call generated by `write.csv` is:

```
write.table(irfilt, "foo.bar", row.n = FALSE, col.names = NA,
            sep = ",", dec = ".", qmethod = "double")
```

Which is why you're getting the error about `col.names = NA` while `row.names = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks -- I keep forgetting about that ellipsis vs. partial match thing.